# Change page controls value after thread finished?

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [asp.net update UI using multi-thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/857999/asp-net-update-ui-using-multi-thread)

I started a thread to process on background.And i want to change my label on page after finished proceess.

But my value doesn't change.

my sample :

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         new Thread(() => ActionStart()) { IsBackground = true }.Start();
    }
    bool _shouldStop = false;

    public void ActionStart()
    {
        while (!_shouldStop)
        {
            // ....

            requestStop();
        }

        //thread finished
        ChangeValue();

    }
    private void ChangeValue()
    {
        lab.Text = "Changed";
    }

    private void requestStop()
    {
      _shouldStop = true;
    }
```

Comment: @Tudor is correct; by the time your thread has finished, the request has gone back to the client; the server has no way of communicating that to the client - the client has received it's message and may never call back. Instead, the client has to initiate the request, via either AJAX or some other method (e.g. ClientCallbacks)

Comment: Using a timer is best solition ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid running this code on a Thread won't help you because you can't make sure the thread will complete before it's to late considering the page life cycle. Generally, the last chance you got to alter a control's value is the it's `PreRender` event, but that depends on how it  has been developed.

However, if you need to do processing in parallel, you still can use a `Parallel.Foreach`, for instance, inside a page event like `PageLoad` to take advantage of parallelism without being asynchronous (`Parallel.Foreach` will only return when all threads complete).